# Как сделать так чтобы кнопка не оставляла отступов. Верстка

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, grid

Учусь делать адаптивную верстку с помощью сетки `grid`. У меня получилось то что я хотел, но в итоге происходит смещение кнопки внутри блока. Это происходит из-за длинны текста. Где-то есть короткие названия товара, а где-то название вываливается на вторую строку и из-за этого кнопка оставляет отступы. Мне нужно сделать так чтобы кнопка была приклеена к самому низу блока и не двигалась в зависимости текста.

**html**

```
<div class="product_grid">
    <div class="product_section">
        <div>
            <a href="{% url 'shop:product_show' product.slug %}">
                <div>
                    <img src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="Изображение - {{product.image.name}}">

                    <div class="product_text">{{product.name}}</div>
                    <span class="product_price">{{product.price}} &#8381;</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <button class="add_to_cart" data-slug="{{product.slug}}">Добавить в корзину</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.product_grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(220px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
    grid-column-gap: 4%;
    padding: 20px;
}

.product_section {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Здесь вы можете заметить, что кнопка `Добавить в корзину` оставляет отступы в некоторых секциях. Например, в товаре с ценой `1920` и `1000` виден некрасивый отступ. Это происходит из-за короткого названия товара. Как сделать так чтобы кнопка была всегда внизу без отступов как в других секциях и не прыгала. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать так:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700&display=swap");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  gap: 3rem;
}
.row > * {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.row .text {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
}
.row .button {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.row .image {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.row .image img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="item">
  <div class="description">
   <div class="image">
    <img src="https://cdn.tmobile.com/content/dam/t-mobile/en-p/cell-phones/lg/lg-q7-plus/moroccan-blue/LG-Q7_Plus-Moroccan_Blue-1-3x.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto, tenetur?
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button">Add to cart</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="description">
   <div class="image">
    <img src="https://cdn.tmobile.com/content/dam/t-mobile/en-p/cell-phones/apple/apple-iphone-xr/blue/Apple-iPhoneXr-Blue-1-3x.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button">Add to cart</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="description">
   <div class="image">
    <img src="https://ecommerce.laraship.com/media/demo/app-iph-x/Apple-iPhoneX-Silver-1-3x.jpg" alt="">
   </div>
   <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora nisi in impedit tenetur dolorem voluptatum unde molestias eligendi.
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button">Add to cart</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо) очень помогло

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение моей проблемы. Нужно было просто поставить позиционирование. И поставить высоту блока.

```
.product_grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(220px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
    grid-column-gap: 4%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.product_section {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 320px;
}

.add_to_cart {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 170px;
}
```

Вот что мне нужно было 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не лучший вариант.

Comment: Если данное решение не очень хорошее. Вы так же можете указать свое. Буду рад